# Opening a port for PLEX - 2 routers

Tags: port-forwarding

I have a D-Link DSR-250n and Linksys Velop Wifi Mesh. The port opening and forward task is something I can't really understand why it isn't working.

**My task is simply to open port 32400 on my public IP address to be able to connect to my PLEX remotely.**

I've tried the following walkthrough on the D-Link.

```
Go to Security > Custom Service.

Name- create a name
Type - TCP
Port Type - Port Range
Source Start Port - 32400
Source Finish Port - 32400
Dest Start Port - 32400
Dest Finish Port - 32400

Save it

Then go to Firewall Rules > add

From zone - Insecure WAN
To Zone - Secure LAN
Service - Scroll to bottom for the one you created above
Action - Always Allow
Source hosts - Any (or if you know the IP of the computer on the internet)
Internal IP address - IP Address of your server
Enable port forwarding - ON
Translate Port Number - 443
External IP address - WAN

Save it
```

Then I've tried to setup port forwarding on my Velop system for the same port.

I know how to identify all my devices in both routers and get their internal IP addresses and MAC addresses, but I'm not doing something right and I've already spent hours trying.

Comment: You should be forwarding all traffic on the outer router to the router connected to your plex server.  The router connected, to your plex server should port foward, traffic to the plex server.

Comment: Is the DSR-250n and the Velop mesh in the same network subnet? Please update the question with the local IP addresses for devices, or appropriate placeholders (like X.Y.Z.123) to help better understand your query.